# System started to hang randomly after power outage

Tags: xubuntu, ssd, error-handling

I've had a power outage recently while I was working in Blender. After reboot I have weird system behavior, it hangs when I work in Blender or scroll sites with Firefox. For instance, I left PC on over night with Blender, Firefox and task manager opened and when I tried to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Blender in the morning and I saw that it's hanging. I tried to close Blender window with x button and via task manager (stop process) but it didn't help and caused task manager to hang. I opened terminal, but it also hanged the second it opened. I tried open TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and it opened and asked me to log in, but after I entered my username - it didn't offered me to enter password, cursor was just blinking below my username. I tried to connect to PC via ssh, but it also stuck at connecting as if PC was unresponsive. I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> but the desktop remained stuck. I used `REISUB` to soft reboot. 
I can't tell if there is any pattern of what causes system hangs. I've already tried boot with Ubuntu LiveUSB and used `fsck` on my nvme SSD, but it found no errors.
How can I define what causes hangs? And what logs should I check?

My specs are:

- Xubuntu 18.04
- AMD Ryzen 5 2600X
- AMD Radeon 580rx
- Corsair 2x8 GB RAM
- Nvme SSD Adata 128 GB

Answer (score 0):

Okay,after all possible checks, it seems to be a faulty nvme SSD. Never had such problems with SATA SSDs and HDDs, I even unplugged them during writing process and nothing dramatic happened. It seems that PCI-E SSDs are more sensible to power outage. Although SMART shows there are no errors on nvme SSD (that's why I was mislead and thought the issue might be somwhere else), I am unable to write anything on it, and reading from it turns into lagfest that freezes system completely. Back to good old SATA drives.